# Interpretation of the single particle spectral function in a spin liquid

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, spin-models

Experimenter here (fair warning).  I've had a question nagging at me for some time revolving around this [paper](https://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.87.045119) by Tang et al. I don't have a good intuition for what the single electron spectral function means in the context of a spin liquid, where the ground state is highly entangled and non local. If I imagine doing ARPES in the spin liquid state of some kiatev material, for instance, would I expect to see weight near the Fermi level corresponding to the majorana modes?  If so, is there a simple picture of how the energy of the photo-emitted electron relates to the uncharged excitations (spinons).  Is there a simple way of connecting this to the 1D physics of fractionalization seen in ARPES experiments on quasi-1D cuprates?

Comment: I don't have the full answer to your question, but I think it might be a mistake asking what the spectral function means in "a spin liquid". Different classes of spin liquids are just too different to allow general answers for a lot of otherwise reasonable questions. Note that the paper by Tang et al. discusses spin liquids with a spinon fermi surface, which are very different from Kitaev spin liquids. I think this will influence the answer here.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Yeah I've seen Tang's paper (there is another along similar lines by Pujara & Lawler) and after talking to others I think I agree that the calculations are too different system to system to draw meaningful comparisons.  I was hoping to gain some intuition about what would be expected in a Kitaev material based on the two aforementioned papers but it sounds like there's not an easy `cartoon` version of what's going on.